# Cakephp 2.5 and memcached expiration

Tags: cakephp, memcached, cakephp-2.5

I am switching my website cache system to use `Memcached engine` instead of using `Files engine`.

I know when I am using `Files`, the cached files were deleted when expiring.

It seems it's not the case with `Memcached`. Can you confirm this?
If it's the case, is there a way to avoid that?

Otherwise, I think the keys will be evicted at some point if they are not deleted, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) does not actively delete expired values. Expired values are deleted when they are accessed or whenever they get evicted.

[MemCachier's](https://www.memcachier.com/) memcached implementation behaves in the same way.

There is also a Redis backed memcached service from [RedisLabs](https://redislabs.com/) but I am not familiar with its expiration behavior.